# OAuth.io undefined error when getting tweets with OAuth.callback for the redirect method

Tags: javascript, twitter, oauth, twitter-oauth

I am using OAuth.io for connecting to twitter. 
Initially i was using the Popup method but for some reason the client machines are having an issue with it in IE11 (popup doesnt close and there is a lost context between the page and the popup).
Anyway, i decided to move to the redirect method.
After redirect, i am able to get the token correctly and have a successful connection. 
When I try however to call the twitter REST API using

```
success.get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Microsoft_EDU&exclude_replies=true')
```

which exactly the same way that works in the popup method, i am getting "error" with no more description

The OAuth call back code that is having a problem :

```
    OAuth.callback(function (error, success) {
    if (error) {
        //handle Error
    }

    success.get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Microsoft_EDU&exclude_replies=true')
        .fail(function () {
            $('#result').html($("error loading Tweets");
        })
        .done(function (data) {
            $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
        });
});
```

Here is the popup method call that is working perfectly and fetching the tweets:

```
OAuth.popup(oauthProvider, function(error, success) {
            if (error) {
                // Handle Error
            }

            success.get('/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=Microsoft_EDU&exclude_replies=true')
                .fail(function () {
                    $('#result').html("error loading Tweets");
                })
                .done(function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(JSON.stringify(data));
                });
        });
```

Any idea what i may be doing wrong or missing ?

Answer (score 1):

After so much trials and errors it turned out the problem was that the line 
OAuth.initialize('KEY'); needed to be right before the callback function :S